How to make rsync continue when it encounters permission errors?
I would like rsync to work more robustly/reliably with my automated file transfer scripts.
One thing I have noticed which seems to make it possibly quit midway in a transfer is stuff like
rsync: opendir "/media/slu/Solidigm/lost+found" failed: Permission denied (13)

lost+found is a dir generated by fsck on ext2/3/4 filesystems and I can't be expected to try to manipulate the permissions on things like that as it may interfere with the operation of fsck. I also cannot be expected to disable/interfere with/configure likely linux-distro-specific configuration or automation that causes fsck to run periodically on disks.
I would like to figure out if rsync can be convinced to ignore and continue when encountering errors of this type.

What makes you think it aborts when finding a directory it cannot list or enter?

AFAIK, rsync does not stop upon the first error trying to find or read files on the source side, but it records the failure and gives a RERR_PARTIAL (23) error code in the end (unless superseded by more critical errors) to indicate that it can't guarantee everything has been transferred.
The man page doesn't say it in so many words, but the

If the sending side detects any I/O errors, then the deletion of any files at the destination will be automatically disabled.  This is to prevent temporary filesystem failures (such as NFS errors) on the sending side from causing a massive deletion of files on the destination.  You can override this with the --ignore-errors option.

For --delete suggests it can only be the case and with --ignore-errors, dirs/files that can't be read would be considered as empty/missing and deleted at the destination with --delete.
If you don't care about the contents of the lost+found directory not being transferred, you can exclude it from the sync with --exclude /path/within/the/source/to/lost+found so that if you get an error, you know it's about files your care about.
I find that --exclude '/path/within/the/source/to/lost+found/**' to only exclude the contents but not the directory itself doesn't prevent the 23 error though.
If you want to treat all files and dirs that you can't read and all dirs you can't search as if they didn't exist, you could build the detailed list of files excluding those with find and use rsync's --files-from:
(
  cd -P -- "$src" &&
    find . ! -readable -prune -o -type d ! -executable -prune -o -print0
) | rsync -av0 --files-from=- -- "$src" "$dst"

(here assuming GNU find or compatible for -readable/-executable and that the source is a local directory).

Thank you. I didn't actually confirm.. i just saw the error show up sometimes at the end of the automation runs, so it's good to know rsync by default behaves in a more useful way than I was worried it was.
